# Syntax on ply, does the comment section matter?

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, compiler-construction, ply

I'm developing a compiler called `medly`, I'm working with ply, a tool which works like `lex & yacc`, but I'm having some problems with the syntax.

This is the lexer:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Lexico.py
# ------------------------------------------------------------
import ply.lex as lex
reserved = {
    'medly' : 'MEDLY',
    'main' : 'MAIN',
    'print' : 'PRINT',
    'if' : 'IF',
#   'else' : 'ELSE',
#   'int' : 'INT',
#   'float' : 'FLOAT',
#   'var' : 'VAR',
    'play' : 'PLAY',
    'repeat' : 'REPEAT',
    'swap' : 'SWAP',
    'aug' : 'AUG',
#   'true' : 'TRUE',
#   'false' : 'FALSE',
    'wind' : 'WIND',
    'lira' : 'LIRA',
    'key' : 'KEY',
    'type' : 'TYPE',
    'len' : 'LEN',
    'random' : 'RANDOM',
    'chorus' : 'CHORUS',
    'while' : 'WHILE',
}
# List of token names.   This is always required
tokens = [
    'LPAR',
    'RPAR',
    'LCOR',
    'RCOR',
    'LLLAVE',
    'RLLAVE', 
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'TIMES',
    'DIV',
    'MENOR',
    'MAYOR',
#   'DIF',
    'EQ',
    'COMA',
#   'PTO',
    'DP',
    'PYC',
    'CTENOTA',
    'CTEI',
    'CTESTRING',
    'ID',
    'TUNE',
    'MAYOREQ',
    'MENOREQ',
    'EQS',

] + list(reserved.values())     


# Regular expression rules for simple tokens
t_LPAR      = r'\('
t_RPAR      = r'\)'
t_LCOR      = r'\['
t_RCOR      = r'\]'
t_LLLAVE    = r'\{'
t_RLLAVE    = r'\}'
t_PLUS      = r'\+'
t_MINUS     = r'\-'
t_TIMES     = r'\*'
t_DIV       = r'/'
t_MENOR     = r'\<'
t_MAYOR     = r'\>'
#t_DIF      = r'\!'
t_EQ        = r'\='
t_COMA      = r'\,'
#t_PTO      = r'\.'
t_DP        = r'\:'
t_PYC       = r'\;'
t_TUNE      = r'\^'
t_MAYOREQ   = r'\>='
t_MENOREQ   = r'\<='
t_EQS       = r'\=='

# A regular expression rule with some action code

def t_CTENOTA(t):
    r'[0-9][A-G][0-5]|[$]'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'CTENOTA')
    return t

def t_CTEI(t):
    r'\d+'
    try:
        t.value = int(t.value)    
    except ValueError:
        print "Linea %d: El numero %s esta muy grande!!" % (t.lineno,t.value)
        t.value = 0
    return t


def t_ID(t):
    r'_[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')
    return t   

def t_CTESTRING(t):
  r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+'
  t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'CTESTRING')
  return t

# Define a rule so we can track line numbers
def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

# A string containing ignored characters (spaces and tabs)
t_ignore  = ' \t'

# Error handling rule
def t_error(t):
    print "Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0]
    t.lexer.skip(1)

import ply.lex as lex
lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input('medly')
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: break
    print tok
```

This is the parser:

```
# Yacc example
#from compiler import ast
import ply.yacc as yacc
import decimal
from compiler import ast

# Get the token map from the lexer.  This is required.
from Lexico import tokens

# Helper function
def Assign(left, right):
    names = []
    if isinstance(left, ast.Name):
        # Single assignment on left
        return ast.Assign([ast.AssName(left.name, 'OP_ASSIGN')], right)
    elif isinstance(left, ast.Tuple):
        # List of things - make sure they are Name nodes
        names = []
        for child in left.getChildren():
            if not isinstance(child, ast.Name):
                raise SyntaxError("that assignment not supported")
            names.append(child.name)
        ass_list = [ast.AssName(name, 'OP_ASSIGN') for name in names]
        return ast.Assign([ast.AssTuple(ass_list)], right)
    else:
        raise SyntaxError("Can't do that yet")



def p_programa(p):
    '''programa : MEDLY DP chorus solo
                | MEDLY DP solo'''
    if len(p) == 5:
        p[0] = p[3] + p[4]
    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = p[3]

def p_solo(p):
    '''solo : MAIN ID notas'''
    p[0] = p[3]  


def p_chorus(p): 
    'chorus : CHORUS ID param LLLAVE notas RLLAVE'
    p[0] = ast.Function(None, p[2], tuple(p[3]), (), 0, None, p[5])

def p_param(p):
    '''param : LPAR  RPAR
             | LPAR n2 RPAR'''
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = []
    else:
        p[0] = p[2]

def p_n2(p):
    ''' n2 : CTENOTA
           | n2 COMA CTENOTA '''
    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    else:
        p[0] =[p[1]]

def p_notas(p):
    '''notas : notas estatuto
             | estatuto'''
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = ast.Stmt(p[2])
    else:
        p[0] = ast.Stmt(p[1])

def p_if(p):
    'if : IF condicion DP notas'
    p[0] = ast.If([(p[2], p[4])], None)

def p_asignacion(p):
    '''asignacion : ID EQ lista PYC
                  | ID EQ music PYC '''
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_lista(p):
    'lista : LCOR n2 RCOR'
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_estatuto(p):
    '''estatuto : asignacion
                | condicion
                | play
                | repeat
                | augment
                | swap
                | tune '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_while(p):
    'while : WHILE LPAR expresion RPAR notas'
    p[0] = ast.While(p[4], p[6], None)

def p_len(p):
    'len : LEN LPAR music RPAR PYC'
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_print(p):
    '''print : PRINT LPAR DP CTESTRING RPAR PYC
             | PRINT LPAR music2 RPAR PYC '''
    if len(p) == 6:
        p[0] = p[3]

def p_music2(p):
    '''music2 : music3
              | music3 COMA music2 '''
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1]

def p_music3(p):
    'music3 : music'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_condicion(p):
    "condicion : comparacion"
    p[0] = p[1]

def comparaMenor((left, right)):
    return ast.Compare(left, [('<', right),])
def comparaMayor((left, right)):
    return ast.Compare(left, [('>', right),])
def comparaIgual((left, right)):
    return ast.Compare(left, [('==', right),])  

binary_ops = {
    "+": ast.Add,
    "-": ast.Sub,
    "*": ast.Mul,
    "/": ast.Div,
    "<": comparaMenor,
    ">": comparaMayor,
    "==": comparaIgual,
}
unary_ops = {
    "+": ast.UnaryAdd,
    "-": ast.UnarySub,
    }
precedence = (
    ("left", "EQ", "MAYOR", "MENOR"),
    ("left", "PLUS", "MINUS"),
    ("left", "TIMES", "DIV"),
    )


def p_comparacion(p):
    """comparacion : comparacion PLUS comparacion
                   | comparacion MINUS comparacion
                   | comparacion TIMES comparacion
                   | comparacion DIV comparacion
                   | comparacion MENOR comparacion
                   | comparacion EQ comparacion
                   | comparacion MAYOR comparacion
                   | PLUS comparacion
                   | MINUS comparacion
                   | CTEI"""

    if len(p) == 4:
        p[0] = binary_ops[p[2]]((p[1], p[3]))

    elif len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = unary_ops[p[1]](p[2])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] 



def p_tune(p):
    '''tune : music TUNE CTENOTA PYC'''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_swap(p):
    'swap : SWAP LPAR music COMA CTENOTA DIV CTENOTA RPAR PYC'
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_expresion(p):
    '''expresion : music MENOR music
                 | music MAYOR music
                 | music EQ music 
                 | music MAYOREQ music
                 | music MENOREQ music
                 | music EQS music'''
    p[0] = p[1] + p[3]  

def p_music(p):
    '''music : lista
             | ID
             | CTENOTA
             | CTEI '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_repeat(p):
    'repeat : REPEAT LPAR music2 DP CTEI DP TYPE LPAR PYC '
    p[0] = p[3] 


def p_play(p):
    '''play : PLAY LPAR music2 DP LIRA LPAR PYC 
            | PLAY LPAR music2 DP KEY LPAR PYC
            | PLAY LPAR music2 DP WIND LPAR PYC'''
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_random(p):
    'random : RANDOM LPAR CTEI RPAR PYC'

def p_augument(p):
    'augment : AUG LPAR music RPAR CTENOTA COMA CTEI TIMES CTEI RPAR PYC'
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_error(p):
    print "Syntax error in input!"

# Build the parser
parser = yacc.yacc()

while True:

    try:
        s = raw_input('medly > ')
    except EOFError:
        break
    if not s: continue
    result = parser.parse(s)
```

My question is:

Does the comment section on the definition on the parser matter?

```
def p_param(p):   

    '''param : LPAR  RPAR                       <------ this part
         | LPAR n2 RPAR'''
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = []
    else:
        p[0] = p[2]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by `comment section ... matter`? Not clear for me(maybe that's because I haven't worked with `lex & yacc` and `ply` as well).

Comment: i cant get the parser to accept any correct input even though i've follow the rules i wrote on the code

Comment: What do you mean by "does the comment section matter"? Of course it matters: the docstrings (comments if you prefer) specify the grammar; ply uses them to build the parser.

Comment: @rici To be fair the idea that docstrings serve any purpose other than documentation is a wee bit counter-intuitive, so it's not as ridiculous a question as you make it sound.

Answer (score 1):

It has already been said in the comments, but just so that the question has a proper answer:

Yes, the docstrings matter. Ply reads and parses the docstrings to get at the grammar rules (or regular expressions in case of the tokens that are defined as functions), which it needs to build the parser.

See also the [documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn23), especially this part:

> each grammar rule is defined by a Python function where the docstring to that function contains the appropriate context-free grammar specification.